# как поменять версию php сервере?

Tags: php

Залил сайт на хостинг reg.ru isp manager,в домене поменял версию на 8.1, сайт корректно запускается, но если проводить какие либо манипуляции через консоль, то ничего не работает
php -v говорит, что актуальная версия 5.4
как так?

Comment: В консоли только через запуск [бинарника](https://help.reg.ru/hc/ru/articles/4408046928401-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8E-PHP-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5#5) нужной версии.

Comment: в Linux из коробки разделены версии для консоли и для веб сервера. Так что ничего удивительного, что веб-сервер работает с новой версией, а консоль - нет

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

После чего увидете что то типо этого

```
  Выбор   Путь         Приор Состояние
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/php8.1   81        автоматический режим
* 1            /usr/bin/php7.4   74        ручной режим
  2            /usr/bin/php8.0   80        ручной режим
  3            /usr/bin/php8.1   81        ручной режим

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Далее вводите номер нужной вам версии и жмете ENTER.

UPD: только для линукса

Comment: Вряд ли на хостинге кто-то позволит выполнять sudo